# How to remap Vim keys (PageUp and PageDown)

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to remap `<PageUp>` to `<C-u>` and `PageDown` to `<C-d>` per the [Vim scrolling documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html).

As it stands right now, my `/etc/vim/vimrc` looks like this:

```
nnoremap <PageUp> <C-u>
nnoremap <PageDown> <C-d>
```

I've tried a lot of different combinations and nothing I've done has worked.

My goal is to make the cursor move to the Start Of File or EOF when holding down PageUp/PageDown. As it is right now, the cursor stops before it gets all the way to the top (and PageDown scrolls past the EOF). Just annoyances I'm trying to fix.

**EDIT:** The above settings work fine. I was placing my mappings too early in the file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about the following mappings?

```
nnoremap <PageUp> gg
nnoremap <PageDown> G
```

Or simply using `gg` and `G`?

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. I'm on Debian, if that helps. Maybe they've set up Vim in a way that I don't understand?

Comment: Wait, yes it did... I've been editing on `/etc/vim/vimrc` instead of `~/.vimrc`. Do key mappings only work in the users' .vimrc file?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu and it works, `gg` is the canonical command for going to the 1st line and `G` the canonical command for going to the last line. Also, `<C-u>` and `<C-d>` stop right at the 1st line and the last line. Please show us your `~/.vimrc` and tell us what version of Vim you use.

Comment: Oh, OK then. **NEVER TOUCH `/etc/vim/`.** Everything you do to customize Vim **must** be done in `~/.vim/` and `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Ha, all of my other settings work in the /etc/vim/vimrc file. I sort of want this to be a global system setting.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of placing the mappings into the system-wide `/etc/vim/vimrc`, you should put user customizations into the `~/.vimrc` file. Nonetheless, the global configuration (if that's what you want) should work, too. That it doesn't means that the mappings get cleared or redefined. You can check with

```
:verbose nmap <PageDown>
```

If it didn't get redefined, you have to hunt for `:nunmap` commands in all loaded scripts (`:scriptnames`), or capture a log with `vim -V20vimlog`.

Comment: If you downvote the answer, please provide feedback why you think it's inadequate.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with

```
map <silent> <PageUp> 1000<C-U>
map <silent> <PageDown> 1000<C-D>
imap <silent> <PageUp> <C-O>1000<C-U>
imap <silent> <PageDown> <C-O>1000<C-D>
```

from [fixing-pageup-and-pagedown](http://vimrc-dissection.blogspot.com/2009/02/fixing-pageup-and-pagedown.html)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, this is actually consistent with what user would expect for the *PageUp* and *PageDown* keys to do.